# bootstrap-select dynamically switch multiple attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm trying to program a function to switch a bootstrap-selectpicker dropdown form multi-selection to single selection mode and then back to multi-selection. That works so far in a jsfiddle I did myself:

html:

```
<body>
  <select id="dropdown-test" class="selectpicker" multiple>
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Barbecue</option>
  </select>
</body>

<button id="btn-switch" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="switchMultiSelect()">Multi-select</button>
```

js:

```
var a = 0;

function switchMultiSelect() {
    if(a == 0){
    $('#dropdown-test').removeAttr("multiple");
    $('#dropdown-test').selectpicker('destroy');
    $('#dropdown-test').selectpicker();
    $('#btn-switch').text("Single-select");
    console.log('remove multiple');
    a = 1;
  }else{
    $('#dropdown-test').attr("multiple","true");
    $('#dropdown-test').selectpicker('destroy');
    $('#dropdown-test').selectpicker();
    $('#btn-switch').text("Multi-select");
    a = 0;
    console.log('add multiple');
  }
  $('.dropdown-test').selectpicker('refresh');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/95799

My web application is quite complex, where I add the options dynamically from a database to the bootstrap-select dropdown. I can switch to single-selection mode, but when I switch back to multi-select the glyphicons appear at the wrong items (not the items that the user selects, instead it marks "n+1"th item of the list)

wrong selection marked

[image: wrong selection marked]

As you see I selected Karlsson and he is correctly added as selection on the top, but the glyphicon-ok appears at Lundqvist

Does someone know where this bug could originate from? I tried so much to get rid of this and nothing seems to help.

Comment: you selector `$('.dropdown-test').selectpicker('refresh');` is class, and you are selecting ID

Comment: i made dummy project it work properly, i think its your selector issue or other js/css files.